# How can applying the first diff of a rebase have a conflict?

Tags: git, version-control, rebase, git-rebase

I have a local branch A that's branched from origin/master that I frequently rebase, and then a local branch B that's branched from A that I frequently rebase.

When I rebase B, it says

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
```

Then it says:

```
Applying: <message-for-A's-first-commit>
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
```

And then I run into conflicts. The conflicts are between the file as it existed in that first A commit and the file as it exists in the most recent commit on A.

I don't understand what's happening here. How could there be a conflict on applying the very first patch? And why is it "applying" what should actually just be the HEAD commit (or is that standard?)?

Comment: Is this because I have rebased B multiple times over time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are it's because you've rebased A, and so now it's trying to resolve the conflict between a commit that was in A (and thus is in B, since B was based off A), and the same commit(s) that are now in A but with a different SHA due to having been rebased.

Rebasing a branch out from underneath another branch is generally considered a bad idea - you shouldn't rebase branches that you've branched from.

Comment: Hmm, what would you recommend instead? Switch to a merge model for both branches?

Comment: If you have two branches which are both being actively developed upon and one of them is based off of the other, yes - use merges, not rebases. Rebase is designed primarily for cleaning up history before it's shared with anything else.

Comment: What's the best way to clean up all those merge commits in the end?

Comment: You don't. If you want to clean up commits you shouldn't be sharing them with other branches. If you want to share commits with other branches, you shouldn't worry about cleanup.

Comment: Why exactly does using a stacked branch model imply that I don't care about clean history?

Comment: @Aaron it doesn't imply it, it requires it. A stacked branch model means that commits in at least one of the branches are "visible" outside that branch, and thus should not be rebased. See the "RECOVERING FROM UPSTREAM REBASE" section in `git help rebase`.

Comment: If you understand what you're doing, you can *partially* rebase your branches (only rebasing certain commits) to clean them up before you merge them, but you have to take care to only rebase commits that other branch(es) haven't seen yet.